# How to call "multiple variable arguments" in Sass or SCSS

Tags: sass

I am trying to combine element/classes with input type, in one mixin Where i have two list one is for classes and one is for required input type check below mixin. But it gives me an error.

```
=input($elements... , $inputs...)
  @each $input in $inputs
    input[type="#{$input}"]
      @content

  @each $element in $elements
    #{$element}
      @content

+input((select,.sample-class),(text,button))
  text-align: center
```

About mixin gives me an error

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "($elements... ": expected ")", was ", $inputs...)"
    on line 1 of ../sass/2-modules/_form.sass
    from line 2 of ../sass/2-modules/_modules.sass
    from line 2 of ../sass/styles.sass
```

required output

```
select{
  text-align: center
}
.sample-class{
  text-align: center
}
input[type="text"]{
  text-align: center
}
input[type="button"]{
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass only **one** *varargs* as a mixin parameter

**UPDATED ANSWER**
Since each *list* passed as a *varargs* argument can contain any number of items, a workaround solution to get your desired result could look like this

```
=input($elements...)
  @each $list in $elements
    $i: index($elements, $list)
    @each $list_item in $list
      @if $i % 2 == 0
        input[type="#{$list_item}"]
          @content
      @else
        #{$list_item}
          @content

//both lists contain 4 items
+input((select,'.sample-class','.sample-1','.sample-1') , (text,button,tel,url,))
  text-align: right
```

Which generates the following CSS

```
select {
  text-align: right;
}

.sample-class {
  text-align: right;
}

.sample-1 {
  text-align: right;
}

.sample-1 {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="button"] {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  text-align: right;
}

input[type="url"] {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Each list can contain any number of items BUT at least One

```
//First list contains 1 item while second list contains 4 items
+input((select), (text, button, tel, url,))
  text-align: center
```

Which generates the following CSS

```
select {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="button"] {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="url"] {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for adding efforts on it. But it won't solve my purpose, 
For an example i was added only 2 in each list, but it can be more or less than that. 

eg. +input((select,'.sample-class','.sample-1','.sample-1') , (text,button,tel,url,))

or it can be single in first list and multiple in second list 

Eg. +input((select) , (text,button,tel,url,))

Comment: You failed to mention that in your question. Please see updated answer. Hope it solves your problem